# Cannot debug Go program in GoLand 2023.2 using go version 1.21.3 on Linux Mint 20.04

Tags: linux, go, jetbrains-ide, goland

I am trying to debug a simple Go program in GoLand. I set a breakpoint and when I press the debug button the program runs to its end and exites with exit code 0. The breakpoint is not hit. The program consists of a simple for cycle. When running it without debugging, it works as expected.
These are GOPATH and GOROOT env variables:
`GOPATH='/home/indiana/go' GOROOT='/usr/local/go'`
Tried some solutions for mac (couldn't anything for Linux that seemed reasonable)
Does someone have any idea where the problem may be?

Thanks in advance,
Indiana

Comment: Does it happen with a hello-world program as well? Or only with an application with loops?

Comment: yes, it happens always. The breakpoints are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Time: 2024-03

Yes, golang 1.21 and 1.22 the same, but go 1.20 is working on IDEA or Golang in debug mode.

You could downgrade golang version to 1.20 for code debug, or waitting Jetbrains to fix the bug.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).